# Axios adds [] at the end of the parameter name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I use `vuejs` with `axios` and `Django` as a server. `Django` expects parameters `travelers` but when I send `travelers` using `axios`, it adds [] at the end so it is `travelers[]`.

How can I stop this?

This is a sample example of my code.

In `VueJS` instance, I have

```
data = {
        filter:{
            travelers:[],
            order:...,
...
```

variable `travelers` can be an array of ids or an empty array. As you can see, I defined `travelers`, not `travelers[]` but it sends it with [].

It's this function:

```
loadOrders: function () {
                        axios.get(this.list_orders_url, {
                            params: this.filter
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            app.orders = response.data;
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error); // todo
                        })
                    },
```

Literally, it adds `travelers[]=1&travelers[]=2` to the query string.

Comment: Use `data` instead of `params`, `params` is for `URLSearchParams` and for those, arrays are sent using `keyName[]`.

Comment: @Titus It is GET request. When I use data, nothing is sent.

Comment: I see, in that case, you can use the `paramsSerializer` property to set how the params will be serialised. [MORE DETAILS](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: In the documentation, the example uses [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) and `qs` has support for multiple array formats.

Answer (score 1):

you can use paramsSerializer with null indexes

```
{
  params,
  paramsSerializer: { indexes: null }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify serialize logic in `paramsSerializer` property to get things working :) 
In this example, I've used [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string), but you can feel free to use any other module or custom method for this.

```js
const queryString = require('query-string');

loadOrders: function () {
                        axios.get(this.list_orders_url, {
                            params: this.filter,
                            paramsSerializer: params => queryString.stringify(params)
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            app.orders = response.data;
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error); // todo
                        })
                    },
```